# Choose the part after WHERE depending on the parameter passed in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I need to substitute query conditions for selecting the number of records depending on the parameter passed

I write 2 queries, but don't know how to combine in 1

**if parent_uid is null I need to execute:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE 
parent_uid IS null AND name = 
:name AND tenant_uid = :tenant_uid;
```

**else:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE 
parent_uid = :parent_uid AND name = 
:name AND tenant_uid = :tenant_uid
```

This is the pseudocode of what I need

```
IF parent_uid IS null 
THEN SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE parent_uid IS null AND name = :name AND tenant_uid = :tenant_uid

ELSE SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE parent_uid = :parent_uid AND name = :name AND tenant_uid = :tenant_uid END IF;
```

```
/**
 * returns the count of categories that contain all parameters passed
 * @param name category name
 * @parm parentUid parent category uid
 * @param tenantUid tenant uid
 * @return count of records
 */
public int checkCategoryUniqueName(UUID parentUid, String name, UUID tenantUid)
{
    MapSqlParameterSource map = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue(PARENT_UID_PARAMETER, parentUid)
            .addValue(NAME_PARAMETER, name)
            .addValue(TENANT_UID_PARAMETER, tenantUid);

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(GET_ECATEGORY_COUNT, map , Integer.class);
}
```

Comment: `WHERE (parent_uid IS null  or parent_uid = :parent_uid)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the IS NULL comparison is only valid if `:parent_uid` is null (not given). Maybe OP could clarify this.

Comment: Can you show us the Java code where you call this SQL query?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: the `IF` statement checks the column name, not a parameter so I am not sure (using the same name for the parameter and the column makes things very confusing I think)

Comment: @deHaar yes, i added

Comment: You could make your SQL query an SQL function with parameters and check the parameter values. Then decide what to do by `IF ...THEN ... ELSE ... END IF`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for ifs.

```
WHERE (:parent_uid IS NULL AND parent_uid IS NULL) OR (parent_uid=:parent_uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You better construct proper SQL string in your language (I guess Java).

```
String sqlParentUid = " parent_uid IS null "
if (parentUid != null) { // parentUid from function
    sqlParentUid = " parent_uid = " + parentUid.toString()
}
```

then just add this part to base sql and run the query